# ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 client side databinding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, asp.net-ajax

I read some articles in MSDN magazine about new features in ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 - primarily client side data binding. I feel MSDN magazine sometimes contains a lot of "marketing" so I'm interested in opinions of real developers. Does it worth it? Do you plan to use it?

**Edit:**

Here are links for articles if anybody is interested. But at the moment it looks like dying framework for enthusiasts only.

- [Data binding in ASP.NET AJAX 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309508.aspx)
- [Conditional rendering in ASP.NET AJAX 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335716.aspx)
- [Live databinding in ASP.NET AJAX 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819084.aspx)
- [Master-detail view with ASP.NET AJAX Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335720.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Microsoft started to favor jQuery over Microsoft Ajax themselves something like half a year ago. Though the new stuff looked great, and I've played with them, I like to use **jQuery** in combination with **jqGrid** myself instead. Besides that there are a lot of plugins available for jQuery as well and I consider that an added bonus.

What I do like, and still use, is the **ASP.NET Ajax control toolkit**. Especially the calendar control in that suite looks cool and most of my clients like me to build it in.

Comment: Does it mean that ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 client side databinding is already obsolete?

Comment: Perhaps not obsolete but one can clearly see that Microsoft's favoring jQuery a lot and has put several proposals like templating, localisation and such to become prime members of the jQuery core library.

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft, jQuery, and Templating](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/16/microsoft-jquery-and-templating.aspx):

> ```
> The ASP.NET Ajax Library
> We are moving the ASP.NET Ajax Library into the Ajax Control Toolkit.
> ```
>
> If you currently use ASP.NET Ajax
>   Library client templates, client
>   data-binding, or the client script
>   loader then you can continue to use
>   these features by downloading the Ajax
>   Control Toolkit.
>
> ```
> Be aware that our focus with the Ajax Control Toolkit is server-side
> ```
>
> Ajax.  For client-side Ajax, we are
>   shifting our focus to jQuery. For
>   example, if you have been using
>   ASP.NET Ajax Library client templates
>   then we recommend that you shift to
>   using jQuery instead.
>
> ```
> Conclusion
> Our plan is to focus on jQuery as the primary technology for building
> ```
>
> client-side Ajax applications moving
>   forward. We want to adapt Microsoft
>   technologies to work great with jQuery
>   and we want to contribute features to
>   jQuery that will make the web better
>   for everyone. We are very excited to
>   be working with the jQuery core team

Once I read this, I stopped thinking using the Microsoft AJAX databinding which was a bit complicated and started using JQuery and it's [JavaScript Micro-Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/). I did really like the idea of two way databinding that the Microsoft AJAX library had though.