# Alternatives to asp.net ajax 4.0 templates

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery

Assuming I'm stuck with asp.net web forms (I'd love to use MVC partial views), are there any good alternatives to asp.net AJAX 4.0 client-side templates?

In other words, is there some way to specify some html, with placeholders for data properties, to which I could then bind a JSON result.  Are there any good jQuery plugins to do this?

I ask because based on the results I'm seeing from Google, this library doesn't seem to be widely used—most search results are from 2008-2010.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591646/asp-net-ajax-4-0-client-side-databinding) seems to confirm that suspicion.

**EDIT**

I despise answering my own question, but [this link](http://www.diplo.co.uk/blog/2011/3/1/using-jquery-templates-to-bind-to-json-data.aspx) (jQuery Templates) seems to me to be the best bet.  If anyone else has any input, please post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely consider [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).  We use them quite extensively in WebForms with ScriptServices as a data provider.  There is a very small learning curve.

Also check out [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/), which integrates seamlessly.

Comment: I have seen jQuery templates, which are great, but I hadn't heard of Knockout before.  It looks amazing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adam, coincidentally, I am using JQuery to retrieve some server side data calling Web Services via Ajax and binding the result on the client side. On my particular case, I am only showing data in a tabular manner, so I am using the [jquery datatables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) (which is fantastic, in my opinion; the API is well documented and easy to extend if you need to).

If you need to show data differently, I think you'll need to write quite a good amount of boilerplate javascript code.

**EDIT:** I just saw your link reagarding Jquery Templates and looks really cool. I didn't know it existed :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link on jQuery Datatables...the template stuff is very very nice, fyi